# Converting columns to rows

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table structure wherein data comes in the following order

```
EmployeeID     TerritoryID 
    1               Abc 
    1               Def 
    2               Ghi 
    2               Jkl 
    2               Mno
```

I need to get the output in the following order

```
1   Abc Def 
2   Ghi Jkl Mno
```

In short i need all territoryID records for EmployeeID in 1 row in multiple columns (dynamic). Basically columns needs to be converted to rows

Any help is appreciated

Thanks and Regards
Sanjai Palliyil

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of a query using pivot and row_number(). Something like this.

```
declare @T table
(
  EmployeeID int,
  TerritoryID char(3)
)

insert into @T values
(1, 'Abc'), 
(1, 'Def'), 
(2, 'Ghi'),
(2, 'Jkl'), 
(2, 'Mno')

select EmployeeID, [1], [2], [3]
from
  (
    select EmployeeID,
           TerritoryID,
           row_number() over(partition by EmployeeID order by TerritoryID) as rn
    from @T
  ) as T
pivot
(
  min(TerritoryID) for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
) as P
```

You need to include as many numbers as the max numbers of territories covered by one employee. If you can't know that beforehand you need to build the query dynamically.